# Difference between note based (MIDI) and sampled (FLAC, MP3, etc.) audio formats

Tags: audio, sampling, sound

I (somewhat) understand sampling and sampled formats, and their relation to the original (analog) signal, but do not quite relate it to note based (MIDI) formats.

What actually is a note based audio format, and is it related to the continuous signal?

Comment: Note-based music formats are not directly related to any signal.  They are more related to the music score sheet that a musician reads before producing any audible sound or signal.  Different musicians might play the same score with completely different instruments producing completely different signals.

Comment: Thank you. So does that mean midi files of recordings of the same score by different artists will be the same since the notes are identical? (I know that the flac/mp3 will be different, but not about the midi)

Comment: Midi also includes some timing and relative dynamics information that will usually differ somewhat between performers.  Midi is usually recorded not from the sound signal, but from the controller buttons/keys/frets/etc.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Yes, I get it now. Thanks! The last line above helped.

Comment: @hotpaw2 If I understood correctly so far, it should be trivial to get an mp3 from a midi, but the other way round should be a proper hard problem especially for a real life audio track with numerous frequencies and instruments. Is there any way it could actually be done? In googling around the topic, I came across some software that claims to do just that..it might be possible mathematically (to list out all the notes, etc.) but could it happen in practice?

Comment: You are right: It's pretty straightforward to generate an audio signal from MIDI information. What you're doing, basically, is to tell a synthesizer or sample player what notes to play when, how loud they should be played, when to "push" the sustain pedal etc. The other way round, generating MIDI from an audio signal, can get pretty complicated. There are approaches, using signal processing to analyze the audio information to determine which notes have been played. This works quite well for monophonic recordings and not so well when trying to decompose, e.g., a complete orchestra recording.